# How do I enable VT-x on the virtualbox of the virtualbox?

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7, ambari

I install Virtualbox5(which is newest version) on Mac mini which has newest version of OS X. Later, I installed CentOS7 on this Virtualbox and install another Virtualbox5 on CentOS7 for setting up Ambari. I am sure the Virtualbox on the Mac is VT-x enable. However, the VT-x setting on the Virtualbox on the CentOS7 is default disable. Is there any way I can enable VT-x on the Virtualbox on the CentOS7?

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
Setting --> System --> Acceleration --> Enable VT-x/AMD-V
```

[image: virtualbox]

Comment: So, this is the closest I've seen, but these options are greyed out for me...do you have any idea of preliminary steps to enable them?

Comment: Did you enable virtualization in host level ? Click new vm and check if you are able to see 64 bit OS , to verify virtualization is enabled in HOST level.

Comment: @ZaneHitchcox Make sure your VM is hard shutdown first